# sed: Getting Two Extra Characters in the Results

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How can I display the next two characters from sed results (wildcard characters and then stop the results)?

```
echo 'this is a test line' | sed 's/^.*te*/te../'
```

Expecting
**test**

Actual results **te.. line**

Comment: a variation on Wiktor's answer ... `sed -En 's/.*(te..).*/\1/p'`

Comment: `echo "..." | grep -o 'te..'` would provide your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n 's/.*\(te..\).*/\1/p' <<< 'this is a test line'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mb48FQ). Here,

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*\(te..\).*` - matches any zero or more chars, then captured into Group 1 `te` and any two chars, and then matches the rest of the string
- `\1` - replaces the whole match with the value of Group 1
- `p` - only prints the result of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `AWK` solution

```
echo 'this is a test line' | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="te.."}{print $1}'
```

output

```
test
```

Explanation: Inform AWK to detect fields like `te..` using `FPAT` (Field PATtern) then just print 1st field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*